# Trying to replace placeholder text with actual data, but it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am building a simple budget app in JS.  Right now, I am able to successfully input an expense or income and display it in the UI.  However, The description does not appear, rather the placeholder text.  [image] . Can does somebody know why?

Below is the UI controller. I created an HTML string with place holder text. Next, I was trying to replace the placeholder text with some actual data, which in this case is the description of the expense. Then I tried inserting the HTML into the dom.

```
var UIController = (function(){
    var DOMstrings = {
        inputType: '.add__type',
        inputDescription: '.add__description',
        inputValue: '.add__value',
        inputBtn: '.add__btn',
        incomeContainer: '.income__list', 
        expensesContainer: '.expenses__list'
    };
    return {
        getInput: function(){
            return {
             type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, //Will be either inc (income) or exp (expense)
             description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDescription).value,
             value: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value
            };
        },
        addListItem: function(obj, type){
            var html, newHtml, element;
            //create HTML string with some placeholder text
           if (type === 'inc'){
            element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;
            html = `<div class="item clearfix" id="income-%id%"> <div class="item__description">%description%</div>
            <div class="right clearfix"> <div class="item__value">%value%</div> <div class="item__delete"> 
            <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button> </div></div></div>`;
           } else if (type === 'exp') {
            element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;
            html = `<div class="item clearfix" id="expense-%id%"> <div class="item__description">%description%</div>
                <div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                <div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                </div></div></div>`;
            }
            //replace the placeholder text with actual data
            newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
            newHtml = html.replace('%description%', obj.description);
            newHtml = html.replace('%value%', obj.value); 

             //Insert the HTML into the DOM
            document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
        },
        getDOMstrings: function(){
            return DOMstrings;
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that you're doing each text replacement on `html` and saving that to `newHtml`, overriding the prior replacement. Only your `%value%` replacement will take effect. You need to use `newHtml` to build the content with your replacements:

```
        newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
        newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
        newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);
```

Comment: I did replace it with your recommendations.  However, now I am getting undefined. Any reason is to why this is now happening?